# Vim autocomplete not working using the key combo

Tags: vim, vi

i am trying to use the auto-complete feature in Vim. When i tyr to use it using the key combo crtl + n
i end up with character ^N on the screen. Apart from that i am also missing various features like search highlight it does'nt show.I am not sure of what is the reason for this pleas find the image,which i am trying to do autocomplete in a file

[click here for the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVsSz.png)

Comment: What does `:imap <C-N>` print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please share your `~/.vimrc` or `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` so then we can see if you have any problem with them.

I started my neovim with `nvim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE` and the key combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> worked nicelly.

You can also run a command to check your key combination:

```
:verbose map <c-n>
```

This will show if you have any plugin or function set to this shortcut.